# Is there any role the jvm of client plays to run the servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jvm

I am confused.

Is there any role , the jvm of client plays to run the servlet ? If it does please discuss it.

If it doesn't how does the servlet's `.class` file manage to run ?

Comment: what was the need to downvote it ! I said i was confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Java on the client has nothing whatsoever to do with running servlets (otherwise servlets would be useless for iPad clients for example)

The server has its own JVM which runs the servlet, no client side code involved except the browser that displays the resulting HTML.